# Changing a field's value from another method

Tags: java, class, field, assert

So I have some code that creates a custom class ArrayUtil, then checks to see if the result of a method in the ArrayUtil class is equal to a certain string.  The code that I have to insert in to the main() method will go where [???] is currently.

```
class ArrayUtil{String opening="["; String closing="]"; String separator=", ";
  public final String format(Object[]array){
    String result=opening;
    if(array.length==0)return result+closing;
    for(int i=0;i<array.length-1;i++){
      result+=array[i]+separator;
    }
    return result+array[array.length-1]+closing;
  }
}
public class Exercise{
  public static void main(String [] arg){
    ArrayUtil u=(new ArrayUtil(){[???]});
    assert "[1; 2; 3]".equals(u.format(new Integer[]{1,2,3}));
    assert "[4; 5; 6]".equals(u.format(new Integer[]{4,5,6}));
    assert "[7; 8; 9]".equals(u.format(new Integer[]{7,8,9}));
  }
}
```

I've identified what the issue is.  String separator (in class ArrayUtil) is "," , whereas the main() method is looking for ";".

What I'm stuck on is changing the separator field's value into ";".
I've tried to change separator like this:

```
ArrayUtil u=(new ArrayUtil(){String separator = ";";});
```

It's not correct.

So my question is: how do I get my String separator to change it's value from the main method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change your seperator you could do this :

```
ArrayUtil u = new ArrayUtil(){
        {
            separator = "; ";
        }
    };
```

Which sets the seperator in an initialization block.

A simpler way might be to just create a normal (not anonymous) instance of ArrayUtil and then change the seperator like this:

```
ArrayUtil u = new ArrayUtil();
u.seperator = "; ";
```

Comment: @user3677898 your welcome, please click the check mark next to the answer to indicate that your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your String variables to static like so...

```
static String opening = "[";
static String closing = "]";
static String separator = ",";
```

and then calling the variable in your main as such...

```
ArrayUtil.separator = ";";
```

and then see if that fixes your problem!

Answer (score 1):

I presume that you cannot change the ArrayUtil class since you have already tried changing the separator. How about using replace method to replace all the ";" with "," before asserting.

```
"[1; 2 ; 3]".replaceAll(";", ",").equals(u.format(new Integer[]{1,2,3})
```

This might not be the answer you are looking for, but otherwise i dont see why you are not able to change the separator unless the ArrayUtil class is not owned by you, in which case as mentioned above your only option is to change the input before comparing if it is known that the two separators will always differ. In case you have the option of changing the ArrayUtils Code, why not change the signature to accept the separtor as another argument to the method or as constructor argument, and you could invoke it like new ArrayList(";")[???]

```
class ArrayUtil{
  ArrayUtil(String separator){
      this.separator = separator;
  }
  String opening="["; String closing="]"; String separator=", ";
  public final String format(Object[]array,String separtorString){
      this.separator = separtorString;
      return format(array);
  }
  public final String format(Object[]array){
        String result=opening;
        if(array.length==0)return result+closing;
        for(int i=0;i<array.length-1;i++){
          result+=array[i]+separator;
        }
        return result+array[array.length-1]+closing;
      }}
}
```